# Application Code must execute Once

Tags: ios

Helllo

how can i execute code only one time at application installed
if application is again open then that code should not be executed
and if it updated then it should be executed

is there other way except `NSUserDefaults` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far and away the easiest way will be to store the initialized version in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSString*       currentVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if(![[defaults stringForKey:@"InitializedVersion"] isEqualToString:currentVersion])
{
    // Initialization code here

    // Mark version initialized
    [defaults setObject:currentVersion forKey:@"InitializedVersion"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```